# DB query vs updating $scope variable in AngularJS & IndexedDB

Tags: javascript, angularjs, indexeddb

I have a 3-step process in my offline app running on AngularJS & IndexedDB.

On page load I make a DB call to list all records with today's date (into a `recordlist` variable):

```
$indexedDB.openStore('records', function(store){
  $scope.todaystart = moment().startOf('day').format(); 
  $scope.todayend = moment().endOf('day').format(); 
  var find = store.query();
    find = find.$between($scope.todaystart, $scope.todayend, false, false);
    find = find.$index("date_idx");
    store.eachWhere(find).then(function(e){
        $scope.recordlist = e;
    });
});
```

Then I can add new records, but in order to update `recordlist`, I'm doing yet **another call**:

```
$scope.addRecord = function (records) {
  $indexedDB.openStore('records', function(store){
    $scope.newrecord = {
      "date": $scope.dateJson, 
      "time": $scope.time, 
      "arrival": '',
      "inserted": ''
    }
    store.insert($scope.newrecord).then(function(e){});
      var find = store.query();
      find = find.$eq($scope.dateJson);
      find = find.$index("date_idx");
      store.eachWhere(find).then(function(e){
        $scope.recordlist = e;
      });
  });
};
```

And finally I update the record with an arrival time, doing **yet another DB call**:

```
$scope.insertRecord = function (record) {
  $indexedDB.openStore('records', function(store){
    store.upsert(
    { 
      "ssn": record.ssn,
      "date": record.date,
      "time": record.time, 
      "arrival":  moment().format("HH.mm.ss"),
      "inserted": true,
    }).then(function (e) {
      var find = store.query();
      find = find.$eq($scope.dateJson);
      find = find.$index("date_idx");
      store.eachWhere(find).then(function(e){
          $scope.recordlist = e;
      });
    });
  });
};
```

My question is, considering that I'm already retrieving `recordlist` on the first call, wouldn't it be cleaner-nicer-easier to update it on-the-fly without having to make a server query on every step (add/insert)?

At the end, the data will be saved anyway, is there a need to retrieve it over and over again with the performance issues that this carries when I could probably just append the new data to `recordlist`?

And if so, how would I do that?

I'm new on working with databases and I'm a bit lost when it comes to best practices and workflow...